# Android: Fast way to "test" app

Tags: android, eclipse, testing

i m starting (or at least trying to) developing android application(s) and I m using eclipse for it along the android sdk.

Now I m wondering if there's a faster way to "test" and tryout something newly writen in the code than starting it in the emulator?

I'm wondering because I m running on 8gb ram and q9550 (quadcore) and it takes some time (let's say 20secs) to upload and start the apk and now

I'm wondering if this really is the only way to test since it requires huge amount of time, especially when I'm trying something new which doesn't work and thus I'm always gotta run it like this let's say like 20 times until I figure out what's wrong with my code...

Comment: Are you closing the emulator window every time? If you leave it open it's a lot faster to load. I usually test on a device as it's much faster, especially post-gingerbread.

Comment: nope I'm not closing it and stil it needs at least 10-20 secs for "uploading", also only very small "hello world" examples. But okay, didn't know about the real devices and since I'm owning an s3, I'm gonna try this maybe :) thanks

Comment: MAC, why did you edit "I'm" to "I m"? Oo As far as I know, the use of "I'm" is correct (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the eclipse toolkit, you have the option to run it directly on a device. It's rather quick to do so.

Enable USB debugging as well as installation of apk from sources other than the market. Then assuming you have already setup the required drivers/settings to connect to your phone via ADB, you should be able to run it on the device and debug. In the run dialog, it will list all available devices and you can simply select the one you want to use.

If you already have a run entry (i.e. you've already run your application),

- select your project
- click Run -> Run Configuration

You should be in your application run configuration (on the left under Android Application -> Your_App).

In the Target tab, you should be able to select your device. It will likely already be in "Automatically pick compatible device...". On my setup, it will run directly on my phone if it's the only available device. You can select Always prompt to pick device which will let you choose every time.

Eclipse plugin (ADT) information: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

Information about setting up your device: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 7):

You can connect your android phone using USB debugging mode and debug your code. If you can't do that, you can export an apk file (which is quick) and use dropbox/gmail to send it to your phone. I am not a big fan of emulator :)

Here's how to enable usb debugging

http://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/

Comment: Okay thanks. But concerning export via dropbox -> Would be even slower :) But I'm gonna try the usb debugging test :) thanks

Comment: Yeah Dropbox is probably slower, but I use it to test post-release behavior. I am just trying to simulate Dev/ QA/ Production environment testings :)

Comment: The dropbox method is rather slow and will not allow you to run the remote debugger.

Comment: @LewisDiamond did you read my comment about emulating Post-release behavior and production environment testings? I have acknowledged Dropbox is slower. However, USB Debugging will only simulate Development environment.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend running on your device rather than the emulator.

- http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

In short:

- Turn on "USB Debugging" on your device.

  - On the device, go to Settings > Applications > Development and enable USB debugging (on an Android 4.0 device, the setting is located in Settings > Developer options).
- Set up your system to detect your device.

  - If you're developing on Windows, you need to install a USB driver for adb. For an installation guide and links to OEM drivers, see the OEM USB Drivers document.
  - If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works. Skip this step.
  - If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, there is a detailed guide in the link above.

Now in eclipse, your device should be available to run on.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Edited to be more detailed.  Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2):

I know **android emulator is too slow**.

You can either use **device** or

try [bluestacks](http://bluestacks.com/) it saves lots of time.

User device only when you want to test your app for particular device.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for :

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

To summarize:

- Plug your phone to your computer with a USB cable.
- Make sure the drivers are installed and your phone properly connected.
- Make a `Ctrl + F11` from eclipse.

It will build the apk, transfer it to your phone and then launch it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you have unit tests, [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/index.html) lets you run them without using the emulator or the device.

Comment: Well, it's not a silver bullet. But it does speed up testing immensely when it works.

Answer (score 1):

you can download *bluestacks* as emulator, as it is really fast.

after then make settings in eclipse as `window->preferences->android->build` -> then uncheck the 3rd checkbox written as "skip packaging and...", then apply and restart the eclipse to take effect.

now open the bluestacks in background and just double click the apk file in bin folder of eclipse and bluestack will install it in 2 to 3 secs and you can directly see the result.

NOTE here that you have to only save the file ,you working on in eclipse and only double click on apk, and result will directly appears to bluestacks. Without uninstalling and reinstalling `apk` in bluestacks.

and you can delete your apk also, it automatically immediately create
a fresh version of apk (thus not required) as soon as you save all your files apk will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Google BlueStacks.

It runs on Windows and it's really fast.